# Privilege list to perform certain activities

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does anyone know if Snowflake, or anyone else, has published a comprehensive list of activities that can be performed in Snowflake and the list of privileges required to allow a user to do that?

For example, to describe a database (Describe Database statement), I think you need the Ownership privilege on the database OR the Monitor privilege on the database.

It would be VERY useful to have a list of common activities and the privileges needed to perform them.

Comment: The Snowflake Documentation has all of the access privileges in pretty good detail.  Have you looked there?

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake documentation contains a comprehensive list on that topic:

**[Access Control Privileges](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html)**

---

> *"For example, to describe a database (Describe Database statement), I think you need the Ownership privilege on the database OR the Monitor privilege on the database.*

[Database Privileges](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#database-privileges)

| Privilege | Usage |
| --- | --- |
| MONITOR | **Enables performing the DESCRIBE command on the database.** |
| ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] | **Grants all privileges**, except OWNERSHIP, on a database |
| OWNERSHIP | Transfers ownership of a database, which **grants full control over the database.** |